# Is 100 the only Leyland number that is a square?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sums-of-squares, pythagorean-triples

[Leyland numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyland_number) (named for Paul Leyland) are positive integers of the form $x^y + y^x$ , where x and y are naturals > 1, and also the number 3. The OEIS link is https://oeis.org/A076980

I thought that this might have some nice bunch of Pythagorean triples generated but I was wrong. In the first 5000 such numbers from https://oeis.org/A076980/b076980.txt apparently the only square is $100$.

Are there any other Leyland numbers that are squares? And why not? What sort of mathematics should I study to understand this?

Comment: Heuristics suggest that $x^y+y^x=z^2$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and $x^{-1}+y^{-1}+2^{-1}<1$ has only finitely many solutions (but it's only a heuristic, and only applies when $\gcd(x,y)=1$).

Answer (score 2):

Here are two unconditional results:

- if $x$ is a power of $2$ then $(x,y)=(2,6)$
- $\gcd(x,y)=1$ or $2$.

---

I thought of this problem in 2019 and posted it on MSE ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292683/is-100-the-only-square-number-of-the-form-abba)), as at that time I did not realise this MO post existed. In Servaes' [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3295955) in the link, the two results are shown. The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3292987) by W-t-P is a detailed version of Gerry Myerson's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320517/is-100-the-only-leyland-number-that-is-a-square#comment799138_320517) above.

Comment: You can link to individual answers and comments.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: fascinating! thanks for the link!!!!!